# embedded table view now shows reduced subviews

Tags: ios, xcode, uicontainerview

I want to embed my table view inside a container view so the cells are not the whole width of my screen.  however no the subviews are also reduced to the container size.  they show up normal size when the app is run but in interface builder they are reduced, making it hard to add any layout features and content.

is there a way of showing them fullscreen?

[image]

shows fullscreen when app run:

[image]

Comment: please make clear your question's meaning, I can not understand.

Comment: the support page is cut off when shown in the interface builder (only shows 1/2) but when built it shows the whole page??.

Comment: change the simulator to `iphone se` have a test, and I think you can use constraits to limit the width or height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Simulated size to Freeform:

[image]